(MLA) Citing from a collection of published letters
I have a book of published letters as one of my sources and am trying to figure out how to properly cite a handful of these letters in MLA format.
The book: The Letters of Emily Dickinson, Harvard Press, 2024.
My citation:

Dickinson, Emily. The Letters of Emily Dickinson. Edited by Cristanne Miller and Domhnall Mitchell, The Belknap Press of Harvard University Press, 2024.

So I am looking to take quotes from some of these letters, which in the book are listed numerically. Letter 1, letter 2, etc. I am a bit unsure on how to do my in-text citations. Here is an example of what I have:

An observation of some of Dickinson’s letters, which she sent often to her friends and colleagues, helps illustrate the wavering nature of her beliefs: “I hope the golden opportunity is not far hence when my heard will willingly yield itself to Christ… how happy if we may be one unbroken company in heaven,” (10) while written elsewhere: “They are religious, except me – and address an Eclipse, every morning – whom they call their “Father” (338).

I have taken to simply listing the number of the letter as it appears in the book, since Dickinson's name is already mentioned. But it seems as though I'm getting conflicting information on how to do this exactly.
